# why signed and zipped app not installed on Android 11?

Tags: android, installation, apk, apktool, zipalign

I disassembled the app using **apktool** and further reassembled it.

After I signed it with **signapk**, but the app did not install on my Android 11 phone, although it did install on my Android 9 emulator. I decided to look at the logs in logcat and saw the following error:

```
Scanning Failed.
PackageManager: com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerException: No signature found in package of version 2 or newer for package com.<application>
```

After googling, I found a solution: use **zipalign**.
I used **zipalign** both before and after signing the application - nothing changed and the error remained. Next, I decided to sign the application with my own key via apksigner. The result is the same.

**jarsigner:**

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore <keystore>.keystore <apk>.apk <alias>
```

I also tried:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystore>.keystore <apk>.apk <alias>
```

**zipalign:**

```
zipalign -p -f -v 4 <input>.apk <output>.apk
```

How to solve this problem?